# Function parameter is not defined in callback

Tags: javascript, html, css, callback, scope

I am trying to get the location of the user and using that I am trying to get the city.
I don't why but when I call the `query` function, the city parameter is having some value but it is not reflected in the callback function's if condition.
However, if I replace the city variable in the If condition with the common String callback function works fine.
the data variable is the array of objects

```
var data = [{ District: "surat", Specialties: "eye" }, ...., {}];
getLocation();
function getLocation() {
  var lat = "";
  var lon = "";
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition, showError);
  } else {
    console.log("denied");
  }
}

function showPosition(position) {
  console.log("2");
  lat = position.coords.latitude;
  lon = position.coords.longitude;
  console.log(lat);
  console.log(lon);
  displayLocation(lat, lon);
}

function showError(error) {
  switch (error.code) {
    case error.PERMISSION_DENIED:
      console.log("User denied the request for Geolocation.");
      break;
    case error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE:
      console.log("Location information is unavailable.");
      break;
    case error.TIMEOUT:
      console.log("The request to get user location timed out.");
      break;
    case error.UNKNOWN_ERROR:
      console.log("An unknown error occurred.");
      break;
  }
}

async function displayLocation(latitude, longitude) {
  let city = "";
  var geocoder;
  geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);

  await geocoder.geocode(
    {
      latLng: latlng,
    },
    function (results, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        console.log(results);
        if (results[0]) {
          var add = results[0].formatted_address;
          var value = add.split(",");

          count = value.length;
          country = value[count - 1];
          state = value[count - 2];
          city = value[count - 3];

          console.log(city);
        } else {
          console.log("not found");
        }
      } else {
        console.log(status);
      }
    }
  );
  await query(city);
}

function query(city) {
  console.log(city); // it is printing Correctly

  var hospitals = data.filter((val) => {
    if (
      val["District"] === city &&
      val["Specialties"].toLowerCase().indexOf("eye") != -1
    ) {
      return true; //instead of city(parameter) if I put a String(For Example"Boston") it works completely fine.
    }
  });
  console.log(hospitals); //hospital array is empty instead of having some value
}
```

Comment: can you provide a working example that illustrates the problem (maybe using the snippet <>)

Comment: I have uploaded some extra code so that you can get what I am trying to say

Comment: It's not really clear why `displayLocation` is async. Just call `geocoder.geocode` and add `query(city)` to the end of ita callback function.

Comment: there's a typo in your code: `Specialities` vs. `Specialties`

Comment: Andy, I have already tried it but it is giving me an empty Hospital array.

Comment: console.log() is your friend to figure out what is not matching `console.log(val['District'], city, val['District'] === city); console.log(val['Specialties'], val['Specialties'].toLowerCase().indexOf("eye"));`

Comment: Since you are constructing the city variable by splitting a string by comma, make sure there are no extra spaces in there, it would be unusual to not have a space after a comma.  `city = value[count - 3].trim()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to return `false` in the filter, if it is not passing your condition - thus, it is better to just write:

```
return val['District'] === city && val['Specialties'].toLowerCase().indexOf("eye") != -1
```

In this case the return value is going to be `Boolean` (`true` if passes, `false` if not).

Also, the `data` variable is not defined in the function. It's better to pass it in as an argument.

And also: the `objects` in the `data` array have a key called `Specialities`, but you are filtering for `Specialties`

```js
const data = [{
    District: "city1",
    Specialties: "yeseye1",
  },
  {
    District: "city1",
    Specialties: "noye1",
  },
  {
    District: "city1",
    Specialties: "yeseye2",
  },
]

console.log('====== old query ======')

function query(city) {
  console.log(city); // it is printing Correctly

  var hospitals = data.filter((val) => {
    if (val['District'] === city && val['Specialties'].toLowerCase().indexOf("eye") != -1) {
      return true; //instead of city(parameter) if I put a String(For Example"Boston") it works completely fine.
    }
  });
}

const a = query("city1")
console.log(a)

console.log('====== newQuery ======')
const newQuery = (city, data) => data.filter((val) => val['District'] === city && val['Specialties'].toLowerCase().indexOf("eye") != -1)

const b = newQuery("city1", data)
console.log(b)
```

#### EDIT: AVOIDING TYPOS

There's a way to avoid typos like the one in your code: use `constants`:

```js
const DIST = "District"
const SPEC = "Specialities"
const EYE = "eye"

const data = [{
    [DIST]: "city1",
    [SPEC]: "yeseye1",
  },
  {
    [DIST]: "city1",
    [SPEC]: "noye1",
  },
  {
    [DIST]: "city1",
    [SPEC]: "yeseye2",
  },
]

const newQuery = (city, data) => data.filter((val) => val[DIST] === city && val[SPEC].toLowerCase().indexOf(EYE) != -1)

const b = newQuery("city1", data)
console.log(b)
```

This way you can choose easier words instead of complicated strings.

#### EDIT 2

Also, you could update this solution if you'd set up the function(s) a bit differently:

```js
const DIST = "District"
const SPEC = "Specialities"
const EYE = "eye"

const data = [{
    [DIST]: "city1",
    [SPEC]: "yeseye1",
  },
  {
    [DIST]: "city1",
    [SPEC]: "noye1",
  },
  {
    [DIST]: "city1",
    [SPEC]: "yeseye2",
  },
]

const curriedQuery = (data) => (filterTerm) => (city) => data.filter((val) => val[DIST] === city && val[SPEC].toLowerCase().indexOf(filterTerm) != -1)

const queryWithCityList = curriedQuery(data) // this sets the list of cities
const queryCityListForEye = queryWithCityList(EYE) // this sets the type of hospitals

const c = queryCityListForEye("city1") // this queries the hospitals in one city -> and gives you the result
console.log(c)
```

This solution seems a bit better if you filter the data source for a certain type of hospital many times over. As you create functions by passing in arguments one by one they are cached (by V8), so working with them becomes faster. (At least theoretically.)

Comment: I tried your code but, b still is an empty array

Comment: @NirDoshi yes - there's a typo in your code: `Specialities` v `Specialties`

Comment: yes I improved it

Comment: but still, b array is empty.

Comment: @NirDoshi then it should work as described

Comment: @NirDoshi there's no `District` in your data - only `city`

Comment: @NirDoshi so, you tried to filter by two keys that don't exist on the object - no wonder it comes up empty :)

Comment: Oh, I am really sorry. I have changed the data(object) a bit.

Comment: @NirDoshi also, if you `await` this function, then it should return a `Promise` and `resolve` this `Promise` somehow - which it doesn't do. You should just simply not `await` it - this function works synchronously just as good (given that the array of hospitals/cities is not too long).

Comment: can you please show me in the snippet you have shared?

Comment: The array of data(array of objects) is pretty long with nearly 3000 values in it. Filtering it would might reduce it to 5-10 values

Comment: @NirDoshi 1500 items are not long for JS. I was talking about tens of thousands or millions of items - and even then, there's a difference if just iterate over this array or you want to render this much items in the DOM.

Comment: currently I want to iterate but ultimate goal is to render filtered item in DOM

Comment: @NirDoshi don't worry about that - that's a task after you solve this one. :) But I cannot really show more than it's in the snippets above. They should work (based on the info you gave)

Comment: I don't why but still my filtered array(Hospital) is still showing me empty.

Comment: @NirDoshi you can test the filtering function by feeding it different city lists - you'll see that it works (I assume, of course). This would mean that the error comes from a different part of your code, not the filtering function itself. Maybe the `city` argument stays empty for some reason? Maybe the data array is not what you expect?

Comment: Thank You muka.gergely. Your guidance really helped me to solve my problem.